# Condescendiente / Condescendant

Tags: traducción, etimología, definiciones

Oh surprise, `Condescendant` has a very different meaning in English compared to Spanish.

[Condescendant](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/condescendant):

> Assuming a tone of superiority or a patronizing attitude

Condescendiente:

> 1. adj. Que condesciende.
> 2. adj. Pronto, dispuesto a condescender.

[Condescender](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=condescender):

> Acomodarse **por bondad** al gusto y voluntad de alguien.

Does anybody have an idea of how the two words, having the same Latin root, came to have such  different meanings in both Languages?

Further, based on the Spanish meaning, how would you then translate `condescendiente` to English?

Comment: Nice and interesting question!

Comment: My answer to the second question is *accommodating*, but Oxford gives *condescending* or *understanding*.

Comment: @PeterTaylor *Accommodating* sounds more appropriate. Condescending, clearly, is not an accurate translation unless Oxford shows a different definition from what Wikitionary shows. Add your comment as an answer. I will upvote now and accept later if no one else can come up with an answer to my first question.

Comment: According to thefreedictionary.com "to condescend" also has 2 different meanings. Maybe the Spanish translation is related to the meaning "To descend to the level of one considered inferior; lower oneself." http://www.thefreedictionary.com/condescend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of [false friend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_friend)  and [possible](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=condescendiente)  an [auto-antonym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-antonym).
1) The English word is *condescendent* or *condescending*

> 1707, prp. adj. from condescend. Originally in a positive sense (of God, the Savior, etc.) until late 18c. Related: Condescendingly (1650s).

2) In other languages (French, Italian, etc.) it retains the "good sense".
3) I would translate it as "affable".

Comment: Great links. It explains everything, I think. Thanks.